# Spring Request Mapping based on any/no query string

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

When using Spring MVC, is there a way to create two entry points by whether or not **any** query string has been supplied in the request.

Something like below where `*` is a wildcard?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"*"})
public String getResourceWithQuery(...)

@RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"!*"})
public String getResourceWithoutQuery(...)
```

**Is this possible with Spring?**

Edit: To be clear, I'm not looking for a particular query parameter, I'm looking to separate the methods by the existence of any query string being present at all.

The fall back is to have one method and then check in code for query parameters and split accordingly. Having a filter method like this is messy and I'd prefer not to have to do this. Unfortunately the splitting functionality by query pattern is common in my code as it is required by the business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One end point is enough.**

You can **set default value** for request parameter(or query string), this will make request parameter **optional**.

As per [java doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#required--),

> **defaultValue:**
> public abstract String defaultValue The default value to use as a fallback >  when the request parameter is not provided or has
> an empty value. **Supplying a default value implicitly sets required()**
> **to false**.

For example,

```
public String doSomething(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "anonymous") final String name) {
```

Comment: I'm not looking to have a default value. Each method will be handled very differently depending on whether or not the query string is present

Comment: Keep it simple, Still, one method is enough, inside this method , get query string and check whether it is exists or not, based on that do  whatever you want. You can separate this logic into another normal  method ( not mapping to any url).

Comment: Filter methods like this are messy and prone to introducing bugs. I'd prefer not to do this if I can avoid it, thus the question. Is what I'm asking for not possible in Spring?

Answer (score -1):

Your are trying to map the request URI which having the query string or not.you are using the params in @RequestMapping which actually use for narrow the Request matching.Read below link
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--
.By using below code you can accept anything after ~/page/ URI.I hope this will help

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getResourceWithQuery(...)
```

Comment: Please add surrounding text which explains why your answer works rather than just a code dump, to help others when they read your answer later.